# Insert Entry at the beginning of Linked List in C

Tags: c

Good evening. For the past month or two I've been busy studying C on my own using the book `The C Programming Language Third Eddition` by Stephen Kochan. I got this far, but, now, for the life of me I can't figure out, Without changing the InsertEntry function, how to insert an entry at the beginning of the linked list below. Can anyone help me out with this or point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

```
//Insert a an entry at the beginning of a linked list
//Cannot change InsertEntry

struct Entry
{
    int Value;
    struct Entry *Next;
};

int main()
{
void InsertEntry(struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EToInsert);

struct Entry N1, N2, N3, N4, Insert, *Start, *First;

N1.Value = 10;
N2.Value = 20;
N3.Value = 40;
N4.Value = 50;
Insert.Value = 60;
N1.Next = &N2;
N2.Next = &N3;
N3.Next = &N4;
N4.Next = (struct Entry *) 0;
Start->Next = &N1;

First = &N1;
InsertEntry(Start, &Insert);


while(First != 0)
{
    printf("%i\n", First->Value);
    First = First->Next;
}

return 0;
}

void InsertEntry(struct Entry *InsertPosition, struct Entry *EToInsert)
{
EToInsert->Next = InsertPosition->Next;
InsertPosition->Next = EToInsert;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InsertEntry` function is designed to **insert after** the element `InsertPosition` so you cannot use it to insert an element at the first place.

In order to insert an element at the first position you would need to do something like this:

```
struct Entry newFirst;
newFirst.Value = 75;
newFirst.Next = oldFirst;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, but I wanted a more knowledgeable opinion. This is the way the author of the book describes how to insert an item into a linked list, then repeats it again in exercise 2 (which is where the InsertEntry function came from), then in exercise 3 he asks this very question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you; consider upvoting. If your problem is solved; mark this (or another) answer as the correct one... this helps other people to see that the question is closed.

Comment: Will do. Your answer was the most helpful, so you get my vote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With `InsertEntry`, no matter what you do, the head of the list remains the same, namely because you don’t even pass it the head of the list.

What you want is a new head of the list. Just create a node, make it the head of “the list”, and set its Next to what was “the list” until then.

You could do this within a function `PrependNode` that creates that new head node, and *returns* a pointer to it so you can assign it to the "the list".

Answer (score 0):

First of all your program won't work at all because `Start` is not actually initialised. You can't use a pointer that points nowhere. Add to that you need to do something like the first answer.

Comment: That's another thing, I was planning putting another structure Entery , N5, in there and setting it to point there, or getting rid of the pointer altogether and pass it like: &Start to the InsertEntry function. Either way it wouldn't have worked anyway. Thanks for your help